# Как вывести данные JSON в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, как прочесть данные типа JSON:

```
{
   "0":{
      "data":{
         "name":"vas",
         "fam":"hri"
      },
      "server_info":{
         "user_id":0,
         "pipe":"msg",
         "event":"message",
         "history":false
      }
   }
}
```

Я пытаюсь - `resonse[0].data.name`, но в ответ только:

> [object Arguments]

Как правильно получить данные оттуда?

Answer (score 4):

```
var json = '{"0":{"data":{"name":"vas","fam":"hri"},"server_info":{"user_id":0,"pipe":"msg","event":"message","history":false}}}';
try {
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    for (var i in json) {
        console.log(json[i].data.name); // vas
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Некорректный JSON: '+e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обращаться к свойствам объекта с помощью `[]`.

```
resonse['0'].data.name
```

```js
var resonse = {
    "server_info": {
      "user_id": 0,
      "pipe": "msg",
      "event": "message",
      "history": false
    },
  "0": {
    "data": {
      "name": "vas",
      "fam": "hri"
    }
  }
};
// При условии, что resonse выглядит так
console.log(resonse['0'].data.name);
```

Comment: @svupol, У меня проблема в том, когда я делаю что-то типо x.y - всё выводит отлично, только сделаю x.y.z - js вообще перестает работать...

Comment: Порядковый номер индекса изменился  и это влияет на значение.

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно счесть данные от туда?

Если ничего за кадром не осталось, то так:

```js
var res = {
  "0": {
    "data": {
      "name": "vas",
      "fam": "hri"
    },
    "server_info": {
      "user_id": 0,
      "pipe": "msg",
      "event": "message",
      "history": false
    }
  }
};
// При условии, что resonse выглядит так
console.log(res[0].data.name);
```

---

**UPD:**

Если таких объектов много:

```js
var res = {
  "0": {
    "data": {
      "name": "vas",
      "fam": "hri"
    },

    "server_info": {
      "user_id": 0,
      "pipe": "msg",
      "event": "message",
      "history": false
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "data": {
      "name": "vas1",
      "fam": "hri1"
    },

    "server_info": {
      "user_id": 0,
      "pipe": "msg",
      "event": "message",
      "history": false
    }
  }
};
// При условии, что resonse выглядит так
Object.keys(res).forEach(function(i) {
  console.log(res[i].data.name);
})
```

Comment: Для такой строки {"0":{"data":{"name":"vas","fam":"hri"},"server_info":{"user_id":0,"pipe":"msg","event":"message","history":false}}} не работает alert(arguments[0].data.name);, всё равно выводит [object Arguments], я точно так же и делал как вы написали.

Comment: Ещё не могу понять, почему к некоторым элементам нужно обращатся чере [] а к некоторым через точку?

Comment: @aHristovsky [Объекты в JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#.D0.98.D0.BD.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.81.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.8A.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.B0). У вас такой же объект или есть, что-то чего вы не выложили?

Comment: Вот таким вот образом у меня json выводится в виде текста $("#log").append(JSON.stringify(arguments)+"<hr>"); , пытаюсь обратится как вы пишете, но либо js вообще перестает работать либо пишет обджект аргументс

Comment: @aHristovsky отмотаем к началу вопроса, выложите в ваш вопрос, то что вы делаете с `arguments`. Желательно с `html`, и `js` кодом, как получаете, куда добавляете, какой конечный результат, чего хотите добиться. А то тут какая-то, каша получается. Четыре ответа и все мимо кассы.

Answer (score 0):

В цикле это будет примерно так

```js
var responce = {
   "0":{
      "data":{ "name":"vas" }
   },
   "1":{
      "data":{ "name":"vas2" }
   }
}

for(var i in responce){
  console.log(responce[i].data.name);
}
```